# Passing content of a LaTeX file as string from Django to React

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs

I am trying to display the content of a LaTeX file using React. The file gets loaded by Django, which passes it to an html file, that in turn passes it on to a javascript (React) file. However, for some reason I can only get the first line of the LaTeX file displayed.

The python method, in views.py that loads the LaTeX file:

```
def index(request):
    lines_list = []
    with open(os.getcwd() + '/latexfiles/example.tex', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            lines_list.append(line)

    lines_string = ' '.join(lines_list)

    context = {'texfile': lines_string}
    return render(request, 'react.html', context)
```

The html file, react.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <div id='root' data={{ texfile|safe }}></div>

{% endblock content %}
```

The App.js file, that is supposed to render the content:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>{this.props.message}</div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The LaTeX file, that I would like to display (as LaTeX code, not PDF):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\author{Jeff Jefferson}
\title{Test document}
\begin{document}
My name is Jeff!
\end{document}
```

If I run this code, only the first line of the example.tex is displayed, i.e.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
```

However, displaying the content of example.tex directly in react.html without calling App.js:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    {{ texfile|safe }}

{% endblock content %}
```

Results in the entire file being displayed.

Also, if I pass the content of example.tex as a string to App.js:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <div id='root' 
                 data="\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
                 \author{Jeff Jefferson}
                 \title{Test document}
                 \begin{document}
                 My name is Jeff!
                 \end{document}">
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Also results in the entire string being displayed on the page.

Does somebody know what I am missing here?